# combining two functions in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have these two functions which have mostly similar code.. so I want to combine them into one function..

```js
previousMonthImg.onclick = function() {
    if (!(monthSelect.value === "Jan" && yearSelect.value === "2010")) {
        monthSelect.selectedIndex--;
        if (monthSelect.selectedIndex === -1) {
            monthSelect.value = "Dec";
            yearSelect.selectedIndex--;
        }
    }
    triggerEvent(monthSelect, "change");
    triggerEvent(yearSelect, "change");
};
```

```js
nextMonthImg.onclick = function() {
    if (!(monthSelect.value === "Dec" && yearSelect.value === "2030")) {
        monthSelect.selectedIndex++;
        if (monthSelect.selectedIndex === -1) {
            monthSelect.value = "Jan";
            yearSelect.selectedIndex++;
        }
    }
    triggerEvent(monthSelect, "change");
    triggerEvent(yearSelect, "change");
}
```

Comment: I would keep them separate. They perform two very different er functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a function to create the event handler.

```
function makeHandler(monthEnd, monthStart, year, inc) {
    return function(){
        if (!(monthSelect.value === monthEnd && yearSelect.value === year)) {
            monthSelect.selectedIndex += inc;
            if (monthSelect.selectedIndex === -1) {
                monthSelect.value = monthStart;
                yearSelect.selectedIndex += inc;
            }
        }
        triggerEvent(monthSelect, "change");
        triggerEvent(yearSelect, "change");
    }
};
previousMonthImg.onclick = makeHandler("Jan", "Dec", "2010", -1);
nextMonthImg.onclick = makeHandler("Dec", "Jan", "2030", 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine both functions as below:

```
monthImg.onclick = function() {
    let maxMonth = 0;
    let minMonth = 0;
    if (!(monthSelect.value === "Dec" && yearSelect.value === "2030")) {
        maxMonth = 1;
    }
    if (!(monthSelect.value === "Jan" && yearSelect.value === "2010")) {
        minMonth = 1;
    }
    if ((maxMonth) || (minMonth)) {
        if (maxMonth) {
            monthSelect.selectedIndex++;
        } else {
            monthSelect.selectedIndex--;
        }
        if (monthSelect.selectedIndex === -1) {
            if (minMonth) {
                monthSelect.value = "Jan";
                yearSelect.selectedIndex++;
            } else {
                monthSelect.value = "Dec";
                yearSelect.selectedIndex--;
            }                
        }
    }
    triggerEvent(monthSelect, "change");
    triggerEvent(yearSelect, "change");
}
```

But it will increase a bit complexity in the function. You can still keep them separated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one:

```
const myNewFunc = (month, year, num) => {
  if (!(monthSelect.value === month && yearSelect.value === year)) {
    monthSelect.selectedIndex = monthSelect.selectedIndex + num;
    if (monthSelect.selectedIndex === -1) {
      monthSelect.value = month == 'Jan' ? 'Dec' : 'Jan';
      yearSelect.selectedIndex = yearSelect.selectedIndex + num * -1;
    }
  }
  triggerEvent(monthSelect, 'change');
  triggerEvent(yearSelect, 'change');
}

nextMonthImg.addEventListener('click', () => {myNewFunc(...)})
previousMonthImg.addEventListener('click', () => {myNewFunc(...)})
```